# How to write a loop to complete the batch rename in R?

Tags: r, loops, rename

This is my code, I want to change the data to the data. The data table has two columns want to delete the second column, change the name of the first column from LAST to r1，r1....rn

```
rawdata.xts_funTS_returns_r0 <- rawdata.xts_funTS_returns_r0 %>% 
  dplyr::rename(r0 = LAST) %>% 
  .[,-2]
rawdata.xts_funTS_returns_r1 <- rawdata.xts_funTS_returns_r1 %>% 
  dplyr::rename(r1 = LAST) %>% 
  .[,-2]
rawdata.xts_funTS_returns_r2 <- rawdata.xts_funTS_returns_r2 %>% 
  dplyr::rename(r2 = LAST) %>% 
  .[,-2]
rawdata.xts_funTS_returns_r3 <- rawdata.xts_funTS_returns_r3 %>% 
  dplyr::rename(r3 = LAST) %>% 
  .[,-2]
rawdata.xts_funTS_returns_r4 <- rawdata.xts_funTS_returns_r4 %>% 
  dplyr::rename(r4 = LAST) %>% 
  .[,-2]
rawdata.xts_funTS_returns_r5 <- rawdata.xts_funTS_returns_r5 %>% 
  dplyr::rename(r5 = LAST) %>% 
  .[,-2]
rawdata.xts_funTS_returns_r6 <- rawdata.xts_funTS_returns_r6 %>% 
  dplyr::rename(r6 = LAST) %>% 
  .[,-2]
```

Comment: Hi @TAT, were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the general idea: loop over each `rn` value, get the corresponding object in your environment, do your dplyr business, then save the result of each iteration within a list where objects indexed by their `rn` value.

```
library(dplyr)

ll <- list()
for(i in 0:6){
  v <- paste0("r", i)
  temp <- get(paste0("rawdata.xts_funTS_returns_", v))
  ll[[v]] <- temp %>% 
    dplyr::rename(!!v := LAST) %>% 
    .[,-2]
}

# Might be convenient to combine each list element into a dataframe
df <- do.call(cbind, ll)
head(df)
#>       r0  r1  r2  r3  r4  r5  r6
#> [1,] 5.1 5.1 5.1 5.1 5.1 5.1 5.1
#> [2,] 4.9 4.9 4.9 4.9 4.9 4.9 4.9
#> [3,] 4.7 4.7 4.7 4.7 4.7 4.7 4.7
#> [4,] 4.6 4.6 4.6 4.6 4.6 4.6 4.6
#> [5,] 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0
#> [6,] 5.4 5.4 5.4 5.4 5.4 5.4 5.4

# Or do it vectorized
tat <- function(i){
  v <- paste0("r", i)
  temp <- get(paste0("rawdata.xts_funTS_returns_", v))
  ll[[v]] <- temp %>% 
    dplyr::rename(!!v := LAST) %>% 
    .[,-2]
}
sapply(0:6, tat)
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
  [1,]  5.1  5.1  5.1  5.1  5.1  5.1  5.1
  [2,]  4.9  4.9  4.9  4.9  4.9  4.9  4.9
  [3,]  4.7  4.7  4.7  4.7  4.7  4.7  4.7
  [4,]  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.6
  [5,]  5.0  5.0  5.0  5.0  5.0  5.0  5.0
  [6,]  5.4  5.4  5.4  5.4  5.4  5.4  5.4
  [7,]  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.6  4.6
  [8,]  5.0  5.0  5.0  5.0  5.0  5.0  5.0
  [9,]  4.4  4.4  4.4  4.4  4.4  4.4  4.4
 [10,]  4.9  4.9  4.9  4.9  4.9  4.9  4.9
```

Example data:

```
iris2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(iris[,1], LAST = 1))
rawdata.xts_funTS_returns_r0 <- iris2
rawdata.xts_funTS_returns_r1 <- iris2
rawdata.xts_funTS_returns_r2 <- iris2
rawdata.xts_funTS_returns_r3 <- iris2
rawdata.xts_funTS_returns_r4 <- iris2
rawdata.xts_funTS_returns_r5 <- iris2
rawdata.xts_funTS_returns_r6 <- iris2
```